# Using SSTP from Linux or Windows to get VPN access to a Microsoft Azure virtual network without using Azure VPN client?

Tags: azure, vpn, azure-vpn

Is it possible to somehow via a command line connect to a Microsoft Azure network using VPN in one of the following ways (I assume that Microsoft's own Windows Azure VPN client is using SSTP internally):

a) Linux: Use SSTP with my Azure Management Portal username and password to connect to a Azure defined virtual network, or

b) Windows: Use the Windows Azure VPN clients (I have access to many Azure VPN virtual networks) to auto-connect and disconnect using a bat file so that the VPN "Connect" dialog is skipped (where I normally just press "Connect")?

Comment: Linux has a `sstp-client` command line tool for you to connect to an sstp server. Check this out: https://sourceforge.net/projects/sstp-client/

Answer (score 1):

For Linux, I'm not able to get it working.

But For windows, below blog is a good reference which works for me

http://www.diaryofaninja.com/blog/2013/11/27/deconstructing-the-azure-point-to-site-vpn-for-command-line-usage